# How to convert Firebase result to List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I wanted to make a list in swiftui from firebase data. So here's my UI
[image]

I've already make a data for that username "mike_one", and it's perfectly working,
this is my xcode result

```
{
IC2ol5bimucKu2d89u2YBz0Bqot2 =     {
    name = mike;
    photo = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-ios-1ed09.appspot.com/o/photo%2Fa2.jpg?alt=media&token=9b6c58f1-eedc-4190-bc63-3f3325c84d77";
    username = "mike_one";
};}
```

And this is my database
[image]

So what i'm asking right now is, How to make the result of the database to be a model? so I can use it as a list.

Please help me.
I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I recommend looking into [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) and read through, for example [this](https://medium.com/@alickdikan/easy-custom-models-and-firebase-in-swift-4-with-codable-43bdb7805b31)
That's basically a way to 'decode' the data you get into Objects defined by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it would not be possible to convert textual firebase data to a List object. A SwiftUI List is defined as

> A container that presents rows of data arranged in a single column

in other words it's a UI element, not a data element.

That being said a List is often backed by an Array or other data storage element. So you'll read Firebase data and store that in an array. Then that array backs your UI List object.

In this case, I would suggest creating a UserClass to hold the Firebase data

```
class UserClass {
   var name = ""
   var photoUrl = ""
   var username = ""
}
```

and then array to store your users in

```
var userArray = [UserClass]()
```

then as data is read from Firebase, create the user objects and populate the array. Your Firebase code wasn't included so in brief

```
firebase.observe.... { snapshot in
   let user = UserClass()
   ...populate user properites from the snapshot
   self.userArray.append(user)
}
```

Then in your view, access the array elements to show them in the List object

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(userArray) { user in
         //do something with each user object
         // like Text(user.username)
        }
    }
}
```